# Google Api for reverse geocoder

Tags: iphone, google-api, reverse-geocoding

I would like to know, whether the url below by google can change in future?
Does the key in this url is app specific?

URL "http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%lf,%lf&output=csv&sensor=false&key=swizzlechops"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This](http://evilrockhopper.com/2010/01/iphone-development-reverse-geocoding/) will surely help you.